# Finding the degree of minimal polynomial of a $10 \times 10$ matrix with entries $a_{ij}=1-(-1)^{i+j}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, contest-math, minimal-polynomials

> **Q.** What is the degree of minimal polynomial of a $10 \times 10$ matrix with entries $a_{ij}=1-(-1)^{i+j}$?

**My approach :** Let the matrix be denoted by $A$. Then $$A=
    \left(\begin{matrix}
    0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
    2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
     0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}\right)
$$

Some observations follow : $\text {Rank} A=2$, $\det A = 0$ and $\text {tr} A=0$.

Since $\det A=0$, there exists an eigenvalue which is $0$.

Since $\text {Rank} A=2$, number of non-zero eigenvalues can not exceed $2$.

Since $\text {tr} A=0$, number of non-zero eigenvalues are either $2$ or $0$.

**Case 1. Number of non-zero eigenvalues is $2$:** In this case they must be $\lambda$ and $-\lambda$ for trace should be zero. Thus the matrix is forced to be diagonalizable. This implies that the minimal polynomial is $P(x)=x(x-\lambda)(x+\lambda).$

**Case 2. Number of non-zero eigenvalues is  $0$:** Here all diagonal entries of the Jordan form are $0$. We have either one $3\times 3$ jordan block or two $2\times 2$ Jordan blocks in order to preserve rank of $A$. Thus the minimal polynomial is $P(x)=x^3$ or $P(x)=x^2$ respectively.

However I checked that for even order matrices with order $\gt 2$ we have eigenvalues of the type we found in Case 1 above. That means for $\text {even $\times$ even}$ matrices, eigenvalues are always $0,\lambda,-\lambda$ for some $\lambda \neq 0$. How do I show this in order to discard the case 2 entirely?

Comment: But how you concluded that the matrix is diagonalizable @Error404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Apply your matrix to the vector
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 1\\-1\\1\\-1\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: This exhibits eigenvalue $-10$ and other answer is regarding eigenvalue $10.$ Excellent!

Comment: Yes, exactly! And either one rules out case 2 immediately, because it shows the existence of a non zero eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2):

Check that $(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $10$.